# how to select columns from multiple models in django?

Tags: python, django

## models.py

```
class Custom_user_model(User):

    daily_target = models.IntegerField()
    monthly_target = models.IntegerField()
    yearly_target = models.IntegerField()
    weekly_target = models.IntegerField()
    call_target = models.IntegerField()
    email_target = models.IntegerField()
    meeting_target = models.IntegerField()
    added_under = models.IntegerField()
    profile_pic = models.TextField()
    doj = models.DateTimeField(default='')
    location_id = models.IntegerField()
    locked = models.BooleanField()
    default_currency = models.IntegerField()
    date_change_permission = models.BooleanField()
    deal_back_log = models.BooleanField()
    created_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    role_id=models.ForeignKey('user_Roles')
    profile_pic = models.FileField(upload_to='.')
    objects = UserManager()

class Deal(models.Model):

    a_choices = ((0,'yes'),(1,'no'))
    approved = models.IntegerField(choices=a_choices,default=1)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Custom_user_model')
    company_id = models.IntegerField()
    contact_id = models.IntegerField()
    deal_title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    deal_value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    currency_id = models.IntegerField()
    process_id = models.IntegerField()
    expected_close_date = models.DateField(default='')
    closed_date = models.DateField()
    deal_milestone=models.IntegerField()
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    s_choices = ((0,'active'),(1,'won'),(2,'junk'),(3,'lost'))
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=a_choices,default=0)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='deal')



class user_Roles(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    permitted_menus = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## views.py

Here, i wrote the code to get columns from three models. But

`Deal.objects.filter(user_id__role_id_id=1).select_related()` returned nothing and `Deal.objects.filter(user_id__role_id_id=1).select_related().values()` returned  the fields from deal model only. It shows 'no fields error', when specifying relationship as values('Custom_user_model__doj').How can i select fields from multiple models?

```
def get_all_normal_users(request,start_date=None,end_date=None):

    query = Deal.objects.filter(user_id__role_id_id=1).select_related().values()
    start_date_range = (
            # The start_date with the minimum possible time
            datetime.datetime.combine(start_date, datetime.time.min),
            # The start_date with the maximum possible time
            datetime.datetime.combine(end_date, datetime.time.max)
        )
    query = query.filter(created__range=start_date_range).values()
    data_dict = ValuesQuerySetToDict(query)
    data_json = json.dumps(data_dict)
    return json_response({'status':data_json})
```

Comment: `Deal.objects.filter(user_id__role_id_id=1).select_related()` did not return a `Deal objects`? Then `.values()` can't return anything too.

Comment: I want the columns from custom_user_model too

Comment: Deal.objects.filter(user_id__role_id_id=1).select_related() returns the json_response as {"status": "[null]"}. If values() is specified the json response is {"status": "[{\"closed_date\": null, \"status\": 0, \"process_id\": 1, \"approved\": 1, \"expected_close_date\": \"2016-04-09\", \"company_id\": 2, \"contact_id\": 2, \"user_id_id\": 13, \"currency_id\": 2, \"source\": \"C\", \"deal_value\": \"2000\", \"deal_title\": \"deal1\",  \"deal_milestone\": 1, \"type\": \"deal\", \"id\": 5}]"}. I want the columns from custom_user_model too@  ilse2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select related values you have to specify all parameters you want in `values()`. Otherwise you will get only the foreignkey to your user model. Try adding the values you want from your user model with `__`:

```
query = query.filter(created__range=start_date_range).values('approved', ..., 'user_id__daily_target', 'user_id__username')
```

Btw if you are creating an API you should have a look at [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Deal.objects.filter(user_id__role_id_id=1, created__range=start_date_range).select_related('user_id').values()
```

or specify required fields as parameters to values().